# Setting unique constraint on all referenced collection members in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

imagine you have a Hibernate/JPA entity class Text which may be annotated with multiple members of class Tag - how would you ensure that Text entity exist only once for a set an arbitrary combination of Tags?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a hash of the keys of the Tags and put a unique key on that.  There isn't really any built in way to ensure a Bag's contents are unique.